# Why does Nikon SB-910 flash fire three times on Nikon D850?

Tags: nikon, flash, hotshoe-flash

I have a new Nikon D850, and I'm using the Nikon SB-910 flash. When I take a shot, the flash pops 3 short flashes. Then the shutter engages, and the full flash goes off. The batteries are OK.

Does anybody have any ideas what the issue could be?

Comment: Also: [Nikon D7000 repeating flash](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/101954/15871)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you have [Red-eye reduction](https://onlinemanual.nikonimglib.com/d850/en/14_using_flash_units_03.html) switched on.

From the linked online manual…

> [image]

The characteristic of red-eye reduction is to pre-flash, one or more times, so your subject's pupils contract, preventing reflection of the flash from the rear of the eyeball.

> [image]